# remove github definition and references

Tags: github

how to remove github definition and references popup on click of any text.

[image]

I'd much rather have it work as plain text copy and select.

Comment: This feature is so annoying. UX regressions make me sad :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can at all. You can either use the "raw" button to get the raw text, but that will also hide all navigation for you.

Another option is to clone the repo locally and navigate it there in an editor / UI of your own choice.

The last option is to use the lightweight VS Code integration that GitHub has, by using the `.` (dot) key on your keyboard. That will give you a VS Code window in the browser which does not use the definition popups. The `.` key works anywhere from the `Code` tab in any repo.
Tip: you can also change the `.com` in the url to `.dev`, that'll do the same thing for you.